# Value of type 'Any' has no member 'valueForKeyPath'

Tags: swift

I was looking other stack overflow questions but it seems like it doesn't work for my case.

I'm making YouTube app and my code is below.

```
     if let JSON = response.result.value as? NSDictionary{

            var arrayOfVideos = [Video]()

            for video in JSON["items"] as! NSArray{
                print(video)

                //Create video onjects off of the JSON response
                let videoObj = Video()
      //I got errors following part
                videoObj.videoId = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.resourceId.videoId") as! String
                videoObj.videoTitle = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.title") as! String
                videoObj.videoDescription = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.description") as! String
                videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url") as! String

                arrayOfVideos.append(videoObj)
            }

            self.videoArray = arrayOfVideos
        }else{
            print("couldn't get video information")
        }
```

I have also a class Video which define title, description and thumbnail.

```
class Video: NSObject {

 var videoId:String = ""
 var videoTitle:String = ""
 var videoDescription:String = ""
 var videoThumbnailUrl:String = ""
}
```

And I got these errors.

> Value of type 'Any' has no member 'valueForKeyPath'

And also this

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do not use `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for your comment! I deleted both of them and all errors above disappeared but 'Type 'Any' has no subscript members' popped up at for statement.

Comment: And that error has been covered here many, many time. Do a quick search. You need to cast properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {

   var arrayOfVideos = [Video]()

   if let videos = JSON["items"] as? [[String:Any]] {

      for video in videos {

          let videoObj = Video()

          if let videoId = video["snippet.resourceId.videoId"] as? String {

              videoObj.videoId = videoId 
          }
          if let videoTitle = video["snippet.title"] as? String {

              videoObj.videoTitle = videoTitle
          }
          if let videoDescription = video["snippet.description"] as? String {

              videoObj.videoDescription = videoDescription
          }
          if let videoThumbnailUrl = video["snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url"] as? String {

              videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl = videoThumbnailUrl
          }

          arrayOfVideos.append(videoObj)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `valueForKeyPath("snippet.resourceId.videoId")` applies `"snippet"`, `"resourceId"` and then `"videoId"`using KVC-based member access. It's not the same as directly applying `"snippet.resourceId.videoId"` to a Dictionary.

Comment: This depends on the actual data structure here i supposed it's the key and it's a beginner mistake of not knowing subscript

Comment: You know you can write a comment before writing an answer by guess.

Comment: @lilisako, have you checked the properties of the `Video` in your `arrayOfVideos`? You may have just checked that there is no compile errors, no?